# MultipartFile: как переименовать?

Tags: java, spring, multipartfile

Всем привет.
В метод приходит `MultipartFile`. Необходимо поменять ему имя, то, которое вызывается методом `.getOriginalFilename();`

Подскажите, насколько это возможно и как это сделать?

В идеале, чтобы было так:

```
@Override
    public Page<ImageFileDto> saveAppCategoryImages(Long categoryId, MultipartFile fg, MultipartFile bg) {
        //здесь происходит переименование
        return save(categoryId, Lists.newArrayList(fg, bg));
    }
```

Comment: Что вы делает с этим файлом? Сохраняете куда-то? или же передаете дальше через REST?

Comment: Передаю в другой метод, который уже сохраняет. Поскольку тот метод уже давно написан и бизнес-логика сохранения тоже, но в них не изменяются имена файлов, хотелось бы именно изменить название файла и передать уже с новым именем, которое будет сохраняться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете изменить `originalFilename` (честным путем, без использования рефлексии) - вероятно, вам придется расширять существующее API для возможности сохранения файла с новым наименованием.